Conditionals with present continuous
"If she was cooking I was usually reading books."
Is this conditional sentence correct? I'm asking because during my research I  was either led to use past simple in both clauses or past continuous but only in one clause.

Yes, it's a valid sentence.

@Kate Bunting What about first conditional and saying " If you are running you are getting tired" instead of "if you run you get tired". Is the meaning the same?

"If you are running (at this moment, I expect that) you are getting tired." Not a very likely thing to say. "If you run you get tired" = The action of running generally causes the runner to get tired.

It is possible to make general statements using the present continuous: If you're running, you're burning calories.  But such statements using the present continuous are most often used as rejoinders to correct what someone else has just said. "I try to conserve energy by running in place. -- If you're running, you're burning calories, even if you're not covering any distance."  Or "I don't really speed when I drive, just 10-15 miles an hour above the posted limit.  --If you're driving 15 miles an hour over the posted limit, you're speeding".

I. Can both clauses in a conditional be continuous ?.
OP's query is:

"If she was cooking I was usually reading books.".
Is this conditional sentence correct?

This sentence is correct but it's not a conditional sentence..
Conditional sentences explain what happens when a particular condition is met and are made up of two clauses (the main clause and the if clause).
Consider:
If you study hard, you will get good marks.
The if clause states the condition, "if you study hard," while the main phrase states the result, "you will get good marks."
II. When do you have two continuous past tense in a sentence?

I'm asking because during my research I was either led to use past simple in both clauses or past continuous but only in one clause.

You were advised correctly regarding how to use tenses in conditional sentences.
One of the clauses of a conditional sentence may contain not only the past continuous tense but also other continuous tenses (link below).
https://www.englishpage.com/conditional/continuousconditional.html
III. Two simultaneous actions.
If we use "while" in place of "if" OP's sentence becomes:
"While she was cooking I was usually reading books.".
Two past continuous tense in one sentence is used frequently to speak about  two simultaneous actions.  The two simultaneous activities are normally connected by the conjunction 'while'.
Ex : John was watching TV while Anne was cooking something for dinner.
IV. Two Present Continuous Tense in a Conditional sentence..
Ref. Cambridge dictionary

Present continuous + present simple.
If the kids are enjoying themselves, we just let them go on playing till they’re ready for bed. (Every time this happens, this is what we do.).
Present continuous + present continuous.
If the economy is growing by 6%, then it is growing too fast. (If it is true that the economy is growing by 6%, then it is true that it is growing too fast.)


Yes, it's valid. The present continuous adds emphasis. Let me put some context around it:

We just didn't have anything in common. If she was cooking, I was reading. If I was napping, she was playing music.

Using the present continuous reinforces that these were extended moments and not one-time occurrences. You could say:

If she cooked, I read.

But it wouldn't have the same impact or effect.
